# Flash Builder undefinned elements generation

Tags: flash, builder

i just started using Flash builder 4 and i have a problem.

As it is based on Eclipse I"m excepting, when I move mouse over undefined Method, class, variable that small Eclipse like window pops up and let shows me some choices for creating interface, class, renaming, classpath fixes etc.

Any way to have this feature enabled in FLash builder? Thanks everyone for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Feature you are talking about is **Quick Fix** . This feature is only available in [FDT](http://www.solutions.powerflasher.com/) . There is currently no support yet in Flash Builder 4.  David Zuckerman made an unofficial Quick Fix [plugin](http://davidzuckerman.com/adobe/2006/05/08/alpha-plugin-featuring-quick-fix-support-and-error-highlighting-in-flex-builder-2-beta-3-released/) for Flex Builder 2 Beta 3. The article is dead now but maybe someone can pick up where he left [off](http://www.davidzuckerman.com/adobe/alpha/update/alphaplugin.zip).

I would not suggest trying to install it unless you know how to use the plugins/svn correctly.